# Read website text content using Web Browser from System.Window.Form in plain C# class

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I am intended to read text content from given url. I have managed to put together logic using HtmlAgilityPack however it is giving me javaScript and other syntax tags, unless I am missing something, however I have found I can use System.Window.Form--> WebBrowser to achieve this. Now I need to achieve this in C# class with no GUI or Window control as I am intended to filter and put in database followed by display on ASP.NET-MVC app.

Now how can I use this library to upload web url and read all the text content, followed by store in string?????

however for reference here is following code using HtmlAgilityPack

```
 public string BuildWebReponseString(string _url)
    {   
      if (obj1.initializeWebURL(_url))
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)

            WebRequest.Create(_url);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);

            WebURLContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

            return WebURLContent;

        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

...

```
   public List<string> StripWebContent(string _url)
    {
        var _responseContent = _reponseObj.BuildWebReponseString(_url);

        if (_responseContent != null)
        {

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

            doc.LoadHtml(_responseContent);

            var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");

            var FilteredWebContent = string.Join(" ", textNodes.Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim()));

            //
            string[] tempString = FilteredWebContent.Split(' ');

            for (int i = 0; i < tempString.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tempString[i] != "" && tempString[i] != null)
                {
                    _WebContentsList.Add(tempString[i]);
                }
            }


            return _WebContentsList;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: what about HttpWebRequest class??

Comment: Do you want to read the generated HTML of a particular website or you want to read the response header from a particular webiste

Comment: system can be given any web address, then I have to code system that it reads all the contents i.e text and / or URLs in website and finally put in string